# Phone Mask does not work before typing

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I have a cellphone bootstrap text box. After i click the textbox i can see the mask but i would like to see the mask as soon as i open the modal.

note:self.EStates stop woking after adding mask.

onload
[image]

after clicking
[image]

```
ko.extenders.mask = function (observable, mask) {
        observable.mask = mask;
        return observable;
    }


    var orgValueInit = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init = function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var mask = valueAccessor().mask;
        if (mask) {
            $(element).mask(mask);
        }

        orgValueInit.apply(this, arguments);
    }

function ViewModel() {
self.cellPhone = ko.observable().extend({
            required: true,
            mask: "(999) 999-9999"
        });

  self.getCellPhoneNumberForAgent = function () {
            var cellPhone = "";
            var responseFromGetCellPhoneNumber = $.getJSON('GetCellPhoneNumberForAgent', function (cellPhoneResponse) {
                cellPhone = cellPhoneResponse;
            }).done(function () {
                var cellPhoneNumberForAgent = $.parseJSON(cellPhone);
                self.cellPhone(cellPhoneNumberForAgent);
            });
        };
        self.getCellPhoneNumberForAgent();


    //This is not working after adding mask code.
    self.EStates = ko.observableArray([]);
        $.getJSON('GetEStates', function (data) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                var name = value;
                var state = new eligibleState(name, false);
                self.EStates.push(state);
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: You've got a mix os extenders, custom bindings, and a jquery plugin for masks. A whole mess. Please explian which technique you want to use, what is the plugin, how you do the bindign, and so on. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery mask isn't really designed to handle programmatically updated values. You need to call `unmask` and then apply the mask again on every update.

```js
ko.extenders.mask = function(observable, mask) {
  observable.mask = mask;
  return observable;
};

var origValueUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.value.update;
ko.bindingHandlers.value.update = function(element, valueAccessor) {
  var val = valueAccessor(),
    mask = val.mask,
    newValue = val(); // Just so it knows when to update
  $(element).unmask();
  origValueUpdate.apply(this, arguments);
  if (mask)
    $(element).mask(mask);
};

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.cellPhone = ko.observable().extend({
    required: true,
    mask: "(999) 999-9999"
  });

  self.cellPhone("1112223333");
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.cellPhone("2223334444");
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="value:cellPhone" />
```

Comment: I just noticed something. I receive some errors: Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return name }"                                                                                             Message: val is not a function

Comment: @Nakres Look for a binding with a parameter of val (like `data-bind="text:val"`) There is something wrong with it: `val` isn't a member of your viewmodel, or you're inside a `foreach` or something.

Comment: I edited my code. self.EStates not working after adding mask.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ko.bindingHandlers.masked = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var mask = allBindingsAccessor().mask || {};
            $(element).mask(mask);
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(element).val());
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            $(element).val(value);
            $(element).trigger('blur');//to show the mask on pageload.
        }
    };



 <input data-bind="value: contactPhone, masked: contactPhone, mask: '(999) 999-9999'" type="text" class="form-control">
```